# I don't really understand PHP

Tags: php, echo

I'm really new to PHP so I was searching for answers to my question, but none of the source codes worked for me, however they seem right and they are approved codes.
I finally got to the point to build my program again from the absolute basics, but instead answers I got just more questions.
My PHP code is here: `<?php echo "<p>WTF</p>"; ?>`

And the result: [image of the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A8HJS.png)

Please someone help me, I think I'm running insane...

Comment: Looks like either you didn't install php in your webserver or you're not even using a webserver to begin with when loading the page. What is the URL in the browser's address bar when you see this result?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5121495/php-code-is-not-being-executed-but-the-code-shows-in-the-browser-source-code?answertab=votes#tab-top

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open your terminal in the folder where your php file is located.
Write

```
php -S localhost:8000
```

and open http://localhost:8000 in your webbrowser.

Comment: Now I do get (in my browser): "The requested resource / was not found on this server." what should I do next  (I do know it), but the question asker on stackoverflow might have the faintest idea on what to do next......

Comment: The command line part seems to work, but if I try to type this in my webbrowser, it returns a 404 error

Comment: When you have your PHP file saved as "test.php", you can try to visit: `http://localhost:8000/test.php` .

Comment: Oh, sorry! Now it's obvious, I am just really exhausted cuz I had an huge exam today.